# Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code on Mac/OSX (drop app in Applications) 
- uninstalled (moved the App to the Trash) 
- installed again

Since the second time I installed I didn't get the same start screen as during my first install I suppose somewhere in my file system Visual Studio Code writes something?
I would like to know where (besides in the Application folder) Visual Studio Code writes files?

Comment: This site is specifically for coding problems. Not for installation problems.

Comment: Ok but when looking on code.visualstudio.com this forum is mentioned: Engage with your peers and ask questions about Visual Studio Code on Stack Overflow. I thought "ask questions" was for every kind of question related to Visual Studio Code. If I can't post it here where should I post my question?

Comment: yeah, well like I said, this site if specifically for problems in your code. I suggest putting your problem on their forum instead.

Comment: A lot of setup and IDE configuration issues are asked (and answered) here on StackOverflow. I'd consider it a fine forum. Though, not having installed [tag:vscode] on a mac yet, I don't know where it stores it's data I suspect somewhere in your home directory.

Answer (score 7):

VSCode uses another folder to store settings, including a flag to indicate if welcome should show or not. The folder is:

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Code
- Mac: $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code
- Linux: $HOME/.config/Code

Answer (score 1):

I've looked on my wife's mac and can't find a trace of these settings, they're not in any standard folder (`$HOME`, `/Libraries/Preferences`, `/System/Libraries/Preferences` nor `/Libraries/Containers`).

But to open the original start screen, you can use <kbd>Help</kbd> -> <kbd>Show Welcome</kbd>.

The settings are stored though, if you run "[defaults read](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118733)" you will see a number of settings related to [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) mentioned, including the files you had open last time you closed. Since Visual Studio Code uses the GitHub Atom Shell under the hood, you need to read the settings for atom using

```
 defaults find atom
```

which will show you some data stored for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Using [fuzzy finder (fzf)](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) I was able to find these directories:

1. Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.microsoft.vscode.sfl3
2. Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/windows.plist
3. Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/data.data
4. Library/HTTPStorages/com.microsoft.VSCode/httpstorages.sqlite-shm
5. Library/HTTPStorages/com.microsoft.VSCode/httpstorages.sqlite-wal
6. Library/HTTPStorages/com.microsoft.VSCode/httpstorages.sqlite
7. Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode/Cache.db-wal
8. Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode/Cache.db-shm
9. Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist
10. Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode/Cache.db

My OS is Sonoma 14.2.1. don't forget about the other locations reported above.

**NOTICE: these are only some of the directories I found, there many more!**

Advice: If what you want is simply to "reset" VS Code, which was my case, all you need to do is delete the *User* and *.vscode* directories which can be found in *"~/Library/Application Support/Code/User"* and *"~/.vscode"*; this will delete all of your files and keep only the app files.